# column-width property in Multiple column layout

Tags: css

Code:

```
<div class="test">content</div>

.test{
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
      column-width: 100px;
}
```

I got one column . But I want 4 columns.

Then I added property

```
column-count: 4;
```

but column width != 100px . Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/9ympv93L/

**CSS**

```
 -webkit-columns: 4 100px;
  -moz-columns: 4 100px;
  columns: 4 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
u have to set the 

.test {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="test">content</div>

.test{
     -webkit-column-width: 100px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     -moz-column-width: 100px; /* Firefox */
     column-width: 100px;
     -webkit-column-count: 4;
     -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
}
```